# hGetLine from /dev/pty/N?

Tags: haskell, terminal, filehandle, pty

I'm trying to read from a pseudoterminal. My eventual goal is to hook up input/output from the pseudoterminal to reactive-banana events, but right now I'm just trying to from the pseudoterminal in Haskell code and write to it in the shell. I have the following code in Main.hs:

```
import System.Posix.Terminal
import System.Posix.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
    (master, slave) <- openPseudoTerminal
    getTerminalName slave >>= print
    hSlave <- fdToHandle slave

    hGetContents hSlave >>= print . take 10
```

When it runs, I see something like:

```
"/dev/pts/7"
```

So I expect that I can write to it with something like this

```
echo "hellllllllllllllllllllllllllloooo" > /dev/pts/7
```

in another shell. But nothing ever gets printed after the `"/dev/pts/N"` line when I run Main.hs --- it looks like it just blocks forever waiting for input. I also tried using `hGetLine` and `hGetChar` in place of `hGetContents`, but with no luck. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you want to read from the master handle?

```
...
hMaster <- fdToHandle master
hGetContents hMaster >>= print . take 10
...
```

Comment: Whoops, that's probably the issue. I'll check later tonight when I get home.